# insert,delete,update (relationship Many-to-Many )

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, ado.net, ef-code-first

in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd742359.aspx described about relationship Many-to-Many data relationships.

now how can perform insert,delete,update on `CourseInstructo`؟

for one-to-man relation This way I do:

```
var  context= new Modle2();
var course= new Course() {title="math",...};
context.Course.addObject(course);
context.SaveChanges()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use navigation property at either end to manipulate the many-to-many relation.
For example,

```
using (var context = new Model2())
{
    int courseID = 4022;
    var course = (from c in context.Courses
                 where c.CourseID == courseID
                 select c).First();

    int personID = 17;
    var instructor = (from p in context.Person
                  where p.PersonID == personID
                  select p).First();

    course.Person.Add(instructor);
    // alternatively, this will also do - instructor.Course.Add(course);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

For removing, use similar logic - for example,

```
using (var context = new Model2())
{
    int courseID = 4022;
    var course = (from c in context.Courses
                 where c.CourseID == courseID
                 select c).First();

    int personID = 17;
    var instructor = (from p in context.Person
                  where p.PersonID == personID
                  select p).First();

    course.Person.Remove(instructor);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Update does not make sense for many-to-many relations - it essentially Add and Remove combination.

Comment: @MaEb, do you get compile time error or run-time exception. Or it just that code runs w/o error but nothing happens. In either case, try posting the relevant code.